# Use Enlive to match a specific TD tag in a group of TD tags

Tags: clojure, enlive

I am just getting started using Elive for an HTML screen scraping task.  If I wanted the text from the second and fourth TD nodes of the following table, how would I specify the selector?  I read through the tutorial but didn't find any examples of how to specify what in XPath would be:

**html/body/table/tr/td[2]** and **/td[4]** (assuming a one-based index)

```
<html>
<body>
<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td width="15%" class="labels">Part No</td>
    <td class="datafield">I2013-00007</td>
    <td class="labels"><div align="right">Parcel No</div></td>
    <td colspan="3" class="datafield">07-220-12-03-01-2-00-000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to capture the text value from those two TD nodes.

Comment: what's your exact problem why you want to read text..?
do you want to replace the content or any other purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nth-of-type` like this:

```
user> (require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])
nil
user> (def test-html 
"<html><body><table width='100%'  border='0' cellspacing='3' cellpadding='2'><tr><td width='15%' class='labels'>Part No</td><td class='datafield'>I2013-00007</td><td class='labels'><div align='right'>Parcel No</div></td><td colspan='3' class='datafield'>07-220-12-03-01-2-00-000</td></tr></table></body></html>")
#'user/test-html
user> (:content (first (html/select (html/html-resource (java.io.StringReader. test-html)) [[:td (html/nth-of-type 2)]])))
("I2013-00007")
```